# Why is Apache2 answering with 301 on a CONNECT method?

Tags: apache, redirect

I have a server under attack (60 million hits and counting!) and I see an access in the Apache2 logs that I think is surprising.

```
example.com:80 [18/Oct/2016] "CONNECT example.com:443 HTTP/1.0" 301 446 "-" "-"
```

*(Note: I simplified the date and remove the offensive IP address)*

My server is not setup to ever understand the CONNECT method, and yet Apache2 seems to do a 301.

Can someone describe what this line of log really means?

Comment: maybe you have a bad  redirect rule somewhere

Comment: Ah... on port 80, I have a forced redirect to port 443... strange that it would not bail out on the "bad" method first, though?! Testing... That's it. I can now reproduce the problem. Since there was 443 in the message, I only checked on port 443... Ha! Ha!

Comment: If you found the problem , that's great!